# Deploy .NET app to Azure using another server database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, azure

Is possible to deploy my .NET application to azure using as connection string another server MySQL database?

I created an application in .NET MVC. It connects to my private server MySQL Database. The application works fine. However, when I deployed it to Azure server, it doesn't working.

When I try to publish, I don't have MySQL as datasource:
[image]

When I run it in Azure server, I get the error:

```
    [MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +1228
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +22
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +218
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +287
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +93
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +65
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +566
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +41
```

My connectionstring:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=myServer;user id=userName;password=Password;database=myDB&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us where your MySQL server is hosted? Is it in Azure, another hosting provider, or on your own machine?

Comment: It's another hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly connect to a MySQL server from an MVC web app. Your MySQL server can be hosted in Azure, AWS, or any other hosting provider that lets you connect to your database remotely. However, making database calls outside of your Azure data enter will cause a delay due to network latency.

Comment: I see, thanks! However, why I can't connect? When I use my local machine, it works fine, but when I publish to Azure. I got the error. BTW, the hosting provider where the MySQL is, was configured to be accessible from both inside and outside of their network

Comment: I would bet that your MySQL hosting provider has firewall rules in place on who can connect. And your Azure data center outbound IP has not been added to the whitelist. Check with your provider to see if this is the case.

Comment: I just did it. Actually I changed my MySQL hosting provider to accept all remote IPs and still the same problem

Comment: Can you connect to your MySQL instance at your hosting provider from your local machine? Just wanted to confirm that.

Comment: The MySQL provider is receiving warning in the MySQL log: [Warning] IP address 'azure-server' could not be resolved: No such host is known.

Comment: It looks like the first time I connect from Azure, it works and open a PROCESS on MySQL. But, after a while the process time get too big (1000) and never closes. Then when I try to connect again it shows: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts